# SQL multiple counts on different columns in the same statement

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table which contains ski resorts around the world. The table also identifies which country and "sector" (USA/Europe/Asia etc.) they are located in. I'm trying to determine the number of resorts in each sector.

Sample Data :

```
resort_id, resort_name, country_id, sector_id
3376       Chréa            204     204
3377       Tikjda           204     204
3384       Beidahu          208     205
3481       Canyon Ski Area  225     206
3482       Castle Mountain  225     206
3483       Drumheller       226     206
3933       Uuperi           240     207
3934       Salomonkallio    240     207
3935       Chabanon         241     207
3936       Le Fanget        242     207
```

I need to be able to determine both the number of resorts and countries in each sector i.e. :

```
Sector    Resorts   Countries
-----------------------------
204          2         2
205          1         1
206          3         2
207          4         3
```

The statement I need is along the lines of :

```
select sector_id,
       count(*),
       // count the number of countries in each sector
from   resorts
group by sector_id
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
select sector_id, count(distinct resort_id) as NumResorts,
       count(distinct country_id) as NumCountries
from resorts
group by sector_id;
```